# Fatal error when building sqlcipher3 from macOS ('sqlcipher/sqlite3.h' file not found)

Tags: c, build, homebrew, sqlcipher

I have been trying to build sqlcipher3 on MacOS with the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/coleifer/sqlcipher3 && cd sqlcipher3
python3 setup.py build
```

I am getting the following error:

```
$ python3 setup.py build
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/sqlcipher3
copying sqlcipher3/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/sqlcipher3
copying sqlcipher3/dbapi2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/sqlcipher3
running build_ext
Builds a C extension linking against libsqlcipher library
building 'sqlcipher3._sqlite3' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src
xcrun -sdk macosx clang -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Qunused-arguments -DMODULE_NAME="sqlcipher3.dbapi2" -I/usr/include -I/Users/gab/Downloads/testbuild/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/module.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/src/module.o
In file included from src/module.c:24:
src/connection.h:34:10: fatal error: 'sqlcipher/sqlite3.h' file not found
#include "sqlcipher/sqlite3.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1
```

But sqlcypher is correctly installed with brew:

```
$ brew install sqlcipher
Warning: sqlcipher 4.4.2 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 4.4.2, run `brew reinstall sqlcipher`
```

And `sqlite3.h` was added in the process:

```
$ find /usr/local/Cellar -name sqlite3.h
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.33.0/include/sqlite3.h
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.34.0/include/sqlite3.h
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlcipher/4.4.2/include/sqlcipher/sqlite3.h
```

Is there something I am missing? Should I be adding a path flag when running `python3 setup.py build`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/sqlcipher/4.4.2/include LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/sqlcipher/4.4.2/lib python3 setup.py build
```

give a try.

Comment: Thats very helpful I tried it and I get further than before but it fails at "ld: library not found for -lsqlcipher
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1" Would you know what the issue is here since sqlcipher is built

Comment: I expanded my answer with the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I guessed the directory, please try.

Comment: It works with `LIBRARY_PATH` (I updated it in the answer) - thank you so much for your help

Comment: Thank you so much, the C_INCLUDE_PATH works for me

Comment: You are welcome. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about the cause of the problem,
but have you considered *manualy downloading it from github and setting it near the code* that uses that?

I know it's probably not the solution you were searching for but it might be all it takes...

Comment: In my example it is downloaded from GH. But this program needs to be compiled to work

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re more likely to find an answer to this on the [SQLCipher discussion board](https://discuss.zetetic.net/c/sqlcipher/5).